# PDFBox throws writeImage error when building on OpenJDK

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm building [this version](https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/commit/735e88528cba4c58ef873bf32cb2dc092c19a543) of PDFBox on Ubuntu with this version of OpenJDK:

```
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.3) (7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

I get the following exception when running the tests:

`javax.imageio.IIOException: Invalid argument to native writeImage`

Expanded:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.JPEGFactoryTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.804 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.JPEGFactoryTest
testCreateFromImageINT_ARGB(org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.JPEGFactoryTest)  Time elapsed: 0.387 sec  <<< ERROR!
javax.imageio.IIOException: Invalid argument to native writeImage
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.writeImage(Native Method)
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.writeOnThread(JPEGImageWriter.java:1058)
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.write(JPEGImageWriter.java:360)
        at javax.imageio.ImageWriter.write(ImageWriter.java:615)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.doWrite(ImageIO.java:1612)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1578)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.ValidateXImage.validate(ValidateXImage.java:63)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.JPEGFactoryTest.testCreateFromImageINT_ARGB(JPEGFactoryTest.java:141)

testCreateFromImage4BYTE_ABGR(org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.JPEGFactoryTest)  Time elapsed: 0.147 sec  <<< ERROR!
javax.imageio.IIOException: Invalid argument to native writeImage
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.writeImage(Native Method)
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.writeOnThread(JPEGImageWriter.java:1058)
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.write(JPEGImageWriter.java:360)
        at javax.imageio.ImageWriter.write(ImageWriter.java:615)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.doWrite(ImageIO.java:1612)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1578)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.ValidateXImage.validate(ValidateXImage.java:63)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.JPEGFactoryTest.testCreateFromImage4BYTE_ABGR(JPEGFactoryTest.java:182)
```

[Searching](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?q=site%3Amail-archives.apache.org%2Fmod_mbox%2Fpdfbox-dev%2F+%22javax.imageio.IIOException%3A+Invalid+argument+to+native+writeImage%22) the archives hasn't shed light.

Comment: Please open an issue with JIRA and post the full exception sequence, so that we can try to output a meaningful error message.

Comment: Done https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2453

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, OpenJDK does not have a native JPEG encoder. Get an [Oracle JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/), and try building with the following command:

`JAVA_HOME="/path/to/oracle/jdk" mvn clean compile`

Comment: Isnt there any alternative solution?